# How to get path of folder with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, file, directory

This is how I open a file and get the file name.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                    QString::fromUtf8("Открыть файл"),
                                    QDir::currentPath(),
                                    "Table (*.csv))");
```

How can I do the same but with the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to get a Directory Name from the Dialog?

If so, take a look at

```
QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory();
```

This below is taken from the QT documentation:

```
QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                "/home",
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

That is Linux based, but can be adjusted for Windows.